# laravel auth routes problem: login and register links don't work

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, routes

I just made a fresh laravel project from scratch and the first thing I did was, I executed

```
php artisan make:auth
```

then migrate it

```
php artisan migrate
```

and open the project in the browser and hit login it says

> Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

Here is the error screenshot:

[image]

and here is the **routes/web.php**

```
<?php
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

Comment: can you share your routes.php file?

Comment: What's inside your routes?

Comment: share your routes file. so we can easily find your problem

Comment: and what is your project url?

Comment: Localhost:8080/bsms/public @John

Comment: But localhost:8080/bsms/public/login doesn't work @John Doe

Comment: @abokorhassan can you try this one?  localhost:8080/bsms/public/index.php/login

Comment: @JohnDoe yeah, that works fine thanks man! but should i specify /index.php every i run my server. i mean when i open the server it will go directly to Localhost:8080/bsms/public not Localhost:8080/bsms/public/index.php

Comment: @abokorhassan ok let see the answer. maybe this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it works for you

First, go to the `project` directory and open the `public` folder and copy `.htaccess` and `index.php` to the `main directory`.
[image]

And Paste it Here in the `Main Directory`.
[image]

Then `open` the `index.php` and replace

`require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';`

and `$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';`

with `require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';`

and

`$app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';`

and save it. then run the project in the browser

`Localhost:8080/bsms/login`.

Comment: i tried this but this isn't working but any way thanks man, imma stick with your answer up there little longer, thats work fine for me

Answer (score 0):

Use this command:

```
php artisan serve
```

If you have PHP installed locally and you would like to use PHP's built-in development server to serve your application, you may use the serve Artisan command. This command will start a development server at `http://localhost:8000`

Later you can check in browser like this: **http://localhost:8000/login**

---

If you have to check without artisan serve

you can check like this(bsms is your laravel-project-name):http://localhost/bsms/public/login

you must have a configuration like this in your [.htaccess](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/.htaccess) file

Comment: But I'm using xampp and everything is working fine but the login and register links dont works, you know they supposed to work after running and auth command right?

Comment: `php artisan make:auth` command will create all of the views you need for authentication and place them in the resources/views/auth directory.

Comment: yes, exactly, but my error is when i hit login or register it doesnt work i mean it says Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

Comment: I think your fresh project laravel installed not successfully, you may also install Laravel by issuing the Composer create-project command in your terminal: `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog` please, installed fresh laravel again

Comment: i tried this but the same error. i solved my problem thanks man for ur contribution!

Comment: if you share the way you solved, maybe it's better